# Ext JS toolbar and breadcrumb example not working in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, extjs

I am new to Ext JS and am trying to create a JSFiddle using the Ext JS Framework (which is included in the list of Frameworks & Extensions provided by JSFiddle)

My Fiddle [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/scirelli/V9sMs/7), and the output pane alone [can be viewed here](http://jsfiddle.net/scirelli/V9sMs/7/embedded/result/).

I am expecting to see a toolbar with a breadcrumb trail underneath.  In fact I see nothing.  I have tested in different browsers but am still not able to see output.

I would like to know why I am not able to see the output on JSFiddle.

---

The JSFiddle draws code directly from [a Github account](https://github.com/scirelli/ExtjsBreadCrumbs) and the relevant section is copied below for reference.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var breadcrumbView = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.BreadCrumbs', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        gtIconCls:'thread-greaterthan-icon',
        removeIconCls:'thread-remove-icon',
        crumbCls:'breadCrumb',

        width   : 700,

        onRemoveItem:function( btn ){
            //This is called when a user clicks on a crumb. The crumb is an Ext.button.Button, if you passed in
            //the optional param 2 to onItemAdded, it will be attached to this btn as _extraData
        }, 
        onRemoveSelection:function( aBtn ){
            //This is called when a user clicks the > button. The > removes all crumbs abover the > button
            //aBtn is an array of the buttons that were removed.
            if( aBtn instanceof Array ){
                for( var i=0,l=aBtn.length,itm=null; i<l; i++ ){
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width   : 700,
        margin  : '5 0 0 0',
        items   : [
            {
                text   : 'Add a crumb',
                scope  : this,
                handler: function() {
                    var text = prompt('Please enter the text for your crumb. Use commas to list crumbs:');
                    text = text.split(',');
                    for( var i=0, l=text.length,itm=null; i<l; i++ ){
                        itm = text[i];
                        //This is how you add an item to the breadcrumb view
                        //Param 1 is some text to show the user
                        //Param 2 is an optional object to attach to the crumb.
                        breadcrumbView.onItemAdded(itm.trim(), {});
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question came to me in a review queue for improvement.  I've edited it to try to make it easier to read and more specific about the problem you are experiencing.  I've also edited the title, so that more people with specific knowledge in this area are likely to see it.  In particular, I've emphasised that the problem is JSFiddle specific and linked to the actual Fiddle with code as well as the output pane. I've also added what you expect to see and what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Fiddle is using Ext JS version 4.1.0, which will fail.  If you change the version of Ext JS that JSFiddle is using to 4.1.1 or above, the output is as expected.

If you start a Developer web console in your browser, and then load the Fiddle, you will see that the script fails with an error:

> `ReferenceError: Ext is not defined`

This means that the base object of Ext JS is not defined.  This might be a bug in how JSFiddle is trying to load the Ext JS framework for 4.1.0 and earlier.

Comment: @richard thanks for your reply...can you tell me is there any other tool where we can make it work...i changed it but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/scirelli/V9sMs/

Comment: That link is working (the one from your comment) for me (Firefox on Windows 8).  What are you expecting?  As far as I can see - it's an empty breadcrumb trail with a toolbar under and a button to add breadcrumbs. I click the button and can add breadcrumbs.

Comment: @J Richard thanks for your reply... i am using mac os firefox in that i am seeing this error... ReferenceError: Ext is not defined..i see empty page even in chrome mac